# Regex: Find everything after a period, before the last slash

Tags: python, regex

I've found some similar regex questions, but I'm striking out at turning those answers into what I'm trying to do.  I have a string like this:

`Y:\Path\sub path\name_of_folder.microphones.flac24\trackname01.flac`

I want to return "flac24"

The number of periods in the name_of_folder will vary.  I've figured out how to isolate the text between the last two slashes, but I can't seem to now get the part after the last period:

`(?<=\\)[^\\]*(?=\\[^\\]*$)`

Thanks!

Comment: Is the target alway the folder of the file?

Comment: Yes, it will always be the parent folder of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a regex, I would do:

```
\.([^.\\]+)\\[^\\]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XtIWMW/2)

Since you tagged this Python, you might also consider just using [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath 

p=PureWindowsPath(r'Y:\Path\sub path\name_of_folder.microphones.flac24\trackname01.flac')

>>> p.parts[-2].split('.')[-1]
flac24
```

Comment: That'll work!  Thanks for the fast help.  I'm trying to get this all on one line because I'm actually passing the regex into the python script as a variable, so I'm using eval() to execute it.  Pathlib looks interesting though.  I'm not familiar with that, but will check it out in the future.

Comment: *I'm actually passing the regex into the python script as a variable, so I'm using eval() to execute it.* Careful with `eval`! There are lots of other ways to pass a regex as a variable. They are just strings so you can pass them easily as a string.

Comment: What would you recommend instead then?  I'm trying to make my python script generic enough that I can build different parsing commands in a configuration file, then use eval() - at least that's what I thought made sense:  For example, I have this ```"Date": "=re.search(r'\\d{4}-\\d{}-\\d{2}',file).group()"``` in a JSON file, and then I do this: ```if settings["tags"][key][0:1] == '=':
    value = eval(settings["tags"][key][1:])```

Comment: Depends if the script is for your own use vs 'in the wild'. If you want to maintain safety, you could do `"DateRE": "\\d{4}-\\d{}-\\d{2}"` inside the config file; detect that key in the JSON, then just use the string inside a regex in your script if it is present or a default if not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
\\[^\\]*\.([^\\]*)\\[^\\]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO5DAr/1). *Details*:

- `\\` - a `\` char
- `[^\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `\` as many as possible
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `([^\\]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `\` char
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `[^\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `\` char
- `$` - end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/t2sHUf):

```py
import re
regex = r"\\[^\\]*\.([^\\]*)\\[^\\]*$"
x = "Y:\\Path\\sub path\\name_of_folder.microphones.flac24\\trackname01.flac"
match = re.search(regex, x)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```